# How can you assert that all std::vector<std::string> are a given size in a one-liner?

Tags: c++, stl, assert

I have a method which accepts a std::vector of sha1 hashes as strings which must exactly 20 characters long. It would be great to assert in a one-liner that this precondition is respected..

```
void MyClass::setSha1Sums(const std::vector<std::string>& sha1Sums)
{
  assert(magic_oneliner_which_verifies_that_all_strings_are_20_chars_long);
  sha1Sums_ = sha1Sums;
}
```

Comment: I think you are working around another problem. The string class can take any length what you should do is introduce a new class (like a std::srting) that can only be created with 20 character strings. Thus you never get to this point with invalid input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++03, with boost (>= 1.33):

```
std::find_if( sha1Sums.begin(), sha1Sums.end()
            , boost::bind( &std::string::size, _1 ) != 20U
                ) == sha1Sums.end();
```

Note that the `!=` is an overloaded operator that boost supplies to make building more complex binds which use basic relational and logical operators simpler.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators

Comment: I would find `std::all_of` (or a crafted version of `all_of` if no C++0x) with the same predicate to be more readable.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: But if I have to craft something new then it's no longer a one-liner which violates the artificial requirements of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `std::adjacent_find`:

```
bool same_lengths = 
    std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string a, std::string b) 
    {
        return a.length() != b.length(); 
    }) == v.end();
```

This looks for two consecutive elements that have different lengths. If all are the same length, it returns the end iterator.

Comment: @Kristian: can always replace the lambda with a `bind` functor

Answer (score 2):

`std::all_of()` returns `true` if the condition is present at every element of the range.

```
bool result = std::all_of(sha1Sums.begin(), sha1Sums.end(), [](std::string &s)
{
    return s.length() == 20;
});
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it in C++0x (once you add a const so it compiles), but it seems the OP wants to use current C++.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: You are right, the parameter should be const. I cranked the warning level up to max in MSVC++ and it compiles without an error or warning.

Comment: I should've said "so it's correct" rather than "so it compiles".

Answer (score 1):

You will need a "for each" function that returns true or false based on the vector that is passed.  You can then in turn pass that function to your vector of strings in your assert statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one liner, but I find this close to the most clear solution in current C++ (instead of std::all_of with a lambda or a foreach loop in 0x):

```
void MyClass::setSha1Sums(std::vector<std::string> const &sha1Sums) {
  sha1Sums_.clear();
  BOOST_FOREACH(string const &x, sha1Sums) {
    assert(x.size() == 20);
    sha1Sums_.push_back(x);
  }
}
```

This also has the slight advantage that you can easily find (e.g. log) the offending string to fix the problem if/when it occurs.